# Vim won't write file without a "!" sometimes (E13)

Tags: vim

Very often (as in multiple times an hour), when I save my file `:w`, vim tells me "E13: File exists (add ! to override)"

[image: Example]

I don't know why it does this, I can't reliably reproduce it, it feels random.

[This](https://github.com/JoshCheek/dotfiles/blob/224c0ec3b18dfed4e22bd42ffd999d7acb29ac9d/vimrc) is my vimrc, note that it sets `nobackup`, `nowritebackup`, and `noswapfile`, and there is a function to strip trailing whitespace that gets run when I save a file.

Also, I tend to have 20 vims open at once, all backgrounded, often editing the same file. Also not improbable that I have the same buffer open in multiple windows (ie `:vsp`) and might open it, then reopen it with the `e` command a lot, possibly from a relative filepath, or possibly from an absolute one (the `cmap %/ <C-R>=expand("%:p:h")."/"<CR>`). No idea if any of this matters. Next time I have this issue, I'll check my `ls` and report anything odd.

#### Update:

When I tried to save "lib/seeing_is_believing/wrap_expressions.rb" (note that this is a different file than the one in the gif), this happened again. Here is the ss, it's buffer 3:

[image: ls]

#### Update2 (for @mMontu)

I just realized that there are two errors happening here. The one in the screenshot is the readonly thing. The one in the gif is the more common one, `E13: File exists (add ! to override)`

The one I just hit is `E13 File exists`, for this one, readonly is not set:

[image: readonly is not set]

#### Update 3

I'm pretty sure the problem is the **ZoomWin** plugin. I had switched it up to a newer version, and it simply didn't work right. So I stopped using it for a bit, and didn't have this issue. Then switched it back, b/c I miss its functionality (it's my favourite vim plugin), and the problems started again. Possibly it's ZoomWin in conjunction with NerdTree window. Probably not the lib authors' faults, vim in general seems fragile and buggy. Maybe I'll try NeoVim, see if they've done a better job. Maybe it's time to try Atom or Emacs again.

Comment: Could it be as simple as the file being changed externally (or in one of your other vim sessions) such that the one on disk is newer than the one in your vim buffer?  My version of vim (7.3 in Mac OSX) issues a warning about this (albeit a different one than you're getting) and requires using `w!` to overwrite the newer file with the older buffer.

Comment: Don't think so, Just made a file, then edited it externally. When I load vim back up, it says `W11: Warning: File "f.rb" has changed since editing started
See ":help W11" for more info.
[O]K, (L)oad File, Load (A)ll, (I)gnore All:`

Comment: Not an answer, but somehow related: [One Vim ... just one](http://vimeo.com/4446112)

Comment: when that happens again, can you check if the `ro` option was set? by `:set ro?[enter]` . I guess some plugin was setting readonly option. If the output was `readonly`, you could see where the readonly was set `:verbose set readonly?`

Comment: Do you ever use the ':file' command to rename files?

Comment: I don't, i always rename them through the shell. But those files have been there longer than I've had this computer.

Comment: What version of vim is this?

Comment: Possible cause: http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/Bug-Report-E13-error-in-v73b-td2256652.html

Comment: Maybe. I'll try Vinegar.vim this weekend and see if it still happens.

Comment: @ComputerDruid 7.4 (got it from homebrew) here is full output: https://gist.github.com/JoshCheek/15e30e176b1b973a8bb9

Comment: @ComputerDruid I deleted NerdTree and switched to Vinegar.vim, it took a while, but eventually the same issue. I think it didn't show up, though, until I started splitting vinegar/netrw panes (I don't really know who they belong to)

Comment: @JoshuaCheek have you tried the `ro` options in my comment?

Comment: @Kent yes. I had updated it in the main post, but said wrong user's name. Anyway, here is an ss showing it, as well. https://s3.amazonaws.com/josh.cheek/images/scratch/vim-ro.gif

Comment: Have you checked to see if the file is getting locked by someone other than you yet?

Comment: I just started seeing the same problem - right after I spent some trying out CtrlP modes other than 'file'.  (For example, I tried 'Buffer', 'MRU', 'Tag', and 'Line' modes for the first time.)  I have `noswapfile`, `nobackup`, and `writebackup`.

Comment: I can confirm that the ZoomWin plugin has this unfortunate problem. I don't think it's related to NERDTree either, since I don't typically have a NERDTree window open but I still see this problem with ZoomWin.

Answer (score 6):

It seems that if there were read errors opening the file, Vim will print an error on `:w`. This can be seen by running `:f`:

```
"MANIFEST.in" [Read errors] 1 line --100%--
```

The errors aren't necessarily errors in reading the contents of file; they can be caused by a plugin.